# How to turn off code 'hints' in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, ide, rider

I've recently started to use Rider, and was wondering how to turn the 'hints' next to the line numbers off (picture attached). I've been through the settings, but not knowing what this feature is called means that I can't find the option. Thanks.

[image: Hints in code]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Features_Unity.html#editor-tips

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I've tried these options and the Unity logo's still dont go away. Thanks.

Comment: I pasted that link to show you what the logo means. That article shows no option to hide the logo.

Comment: File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Gutter Icons
to configure (most) of gutter icons or completely switch them off

Answer (score 0):

This named `Inlay Hints`
You can customize not only this, but also the same hints in the code